# Implicit narrowing rules in java

Tags: java, narrowing

```
byte b = 0xFFFFFFFF; //OK, because integer -1 sits between -128 and 127, FINE!!
char ch = 0xFFFFFFFF; //Not OK, because integer -1 does not sit between 0 and 65535, FINE!!
byte b = 0L; //Compiler says Not OK? But long integer 0 sits between -128 and 127?
```

I am not convinced with narrowing rule applied by the java compiler in third line of above code.

Please help me understand, the logic behind this narrowing rule.

Answer (score 3):

The `L` suffix on the literal `0L` makes this literal of type `long` (a 64-bit signed integer).

There is no implicit narrowing from `long` to `byte`, according to the rules of the Java language.

See Java Language Specification [section 5.2 Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Note that the type of the constant expression does not include `long`.

Comment: Whichever rule had narrowed integer to byte in my above code, Can't same rule be applied for long(64 bit) to byte(8 bit)?

Comment: @overexchange the first line is a _numeric_ literal - it can be _assigned_ to a `byte`. The third line is a `long` because you asked for one explicitly. A `long` can never be assigned to a `byte`. One might argue that the compiler could check a compile time constant, but it doesn't - them's the rules.

Comment: @overexchange added link and relevant quote from the JLS.

Comment: I had been thru the rule of narrowing. I am trying to say that it does not make sense to me. why? If integer is narrowed to byte then long integer should be narrowed to byte, otherwise you are forcing me to mug up these rules without conceptual logic. this is tough!!

Comment: @overexchange It's hard to say why the rules are what they are; if you really want to know, you'd have to ask the designers of the Java language. In this case there's no real hard technical reason why it should be like it is, this is just how the designers chose the rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of casting a primitive data type into another. Explicit and Implicit.

Implicit casting as in your case `byte b = 0L;` gives compilation error as there is a possible loss of information.

If you change it like this:

```
byte b=(byte)0L;
```

Then there will be no compiler error, as you are telling compiler explicitely for the conversion.

Comment: there is nothing like explicit and implicit casting. we have widening(implicit), narrowing(implicit) and casting(explicit) in java